# Is AMD Opteron 3280, 8 cores, 32 GB DDR3 RAM will able to run 200 rails application and 200 mysql database

Tags: linux, nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, dedicated-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

I am planning to hosing an rails application + Mysql in dedicated server

maximum 200 replicated rails application with 200 unique databases

simply for understanding

```
www.client1.product.com   use client1 rails application connected with database name client1
www.client2.product.com   use  client2 rails application connected with database name client2
```

**Each database has 90 tables, so client1 will use one Database with 90 tables**

we can calculate for 200 rails app means 200 databases so (200 * 90 tables = 18000 tables)

***What my question is whether the following server hardware configuration can able to handle 200 unique rails app phusion passenger instance with 200 unique databases***

**Total Server Load Assumptions:**

> Average concurrent http connections to my server is 300
>
> At peak Day time http connections may vary from 500 to 2000
>
> Each client will have maximum db size of 1 GB (if my application runs
>   beyond 4 years) , 
>     so 200 clients * 1 GB DB = 200 GB (ie each DB of 1 GB
>   size)

**OS** - Centos or Ubuntu

**Dedicated server configuration:**

```
CPU         AMD Opteron™ 3280
Quantity    Octo-Core
Clock Rate  8x 2.4 GHz (so total 19.2 GHz)
Processor passmark score is 5722 [http://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD+Opteron+3280]


Main Memory

Capacity    32 GB RAM
Type    DIMM (DDR3)

Hard Disks

Quantity    2
Capacity    2,000 GB (ie) 2 TB + 2 TB
Type    SATA II, 7,200 rpm, 8 MB
RAID    RAID 1 by software

Mainboard

Chipset AMD 880G
Network Broadcom BCM57780
```

**Application Info:**

For simple understanding , Rails application source code is same but with different databases.
 Each client should have seperate DB and separate rails instance. I am replicating - duplicating code for each client with separate folders and giving different database names and so each serving as an different instance.

For Example:

I am having one primary temp domain

```
www.product.com
```

For each client i need to have separate sub domain mapped to same server with same port(80) but with different rails instance name

```
www.client1.product.com
www.client2.product.com
www.clientn.product.com
```

**Application Architecture:**

With ***Phusion Passenger + Nginx***, the easiest way to achieve  VHOST.

my project in different folders :

/var/www/rails/client1/
/var/www/rails/client2/
/var/www/rails/client3/
/var/www/rails/client4/
Then make a VHOST file for each of your client in /etc/apache2/sites-available/client1.product.com

ServerName client1.product.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/rails/client1/current/public

```
    <Directory /var/www/rails/client1/current/public>
            Allow from all
            Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
```

**Any reviews and comments about server configuration and application architecture are always welcome and i am glad to take it.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea. Noone has. Because we have ZERO ideas where your bottlenecks are and how much Memory, CPU and IO every application uses, nor how many users they have.

Could work, could blow. Sit down and test it.

if all 200 gb's are active at the same time, yo have a terrific 153,6 mb per application (assuming 2gb for overhad and OS) which may work, but only about 2 IOPS on the disc side.

I personally would go to a 6xxx level dual socket board, plug in one CPU with 16 cores and 64gb memory and add a second CPU as needed.

But only you can say. This is what labs are for.

Comment: I have updated my question and added more information in Total Server Load Assumptions: